# Title font makes I and l indistinct

Tags: discussion, markdown, information-display

The title of this question is:

> Title font makes I and l indistinct

```
Title font makes I and l indistinct
```

The font used for question titles makes uppercase 'i' and lowercase 'L' (I and l) visually identical, or nearly so. (I see on close inspection that there's a very small hook at the bottom of the lowercase `l`, but if the actual letter is uppercase `I` it's hard to tell that it's not supposed to be `l`.)

(At least in my browser, the variable-width font has the same problem, but the fixed-width code font does not.)

Usually this doesn't make much difference, but for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11889744/827263) <strike>it caused one person to misunderstand the question</strike> the difference could be significant. (On re-reading the person's (now deleted) answer, he didn't confuse `I` and `l`; he assumed that `I` was supposed to be `i`, which isn't related to the font after all.)

I see this on Windows 7 using Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

Can something be done about this?

(Somehow I suspect that any solution won't work everywhere and/or will annoy a lot of people, but I thought I'd bring it up anyway.)

Related (but not the same): [code font doesn't distinguish 1 and l](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76837/167210)

Obligatory screen capture with freehand circles:

> [image: Screen capture of this very question]

Comment: Shhhhhhhhh! Don't call attention to the "`probIem`" workaround!

Comment: SO/MSO uses Trebuchet MS for question titles, whose lowercase L has a tail. It's pretty easy to spot, at least for me.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: The tail on the `l` is visible, but it's easy to think that an `I` is really a tailless `l` if you don't know that `l` has a tail.

Comment: Oh, the Illiterates!

Answer (score 2):

There aren't very many "pretty" sans-serif fonts around that solve this better than the current one. In fact, many of them are a lot worse, believe it or not. Have a look at the current font-stack for titles, which handle this problem progressively worse:

```
Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif
```

I still gave the Question a +1, because this kind of distinction is rather important, especially on a programming forum like SO. However, next to choosing a [programming font](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/progamming-fonts.html) I think the only two available options are:

1. Stick with the current font.
2. Move to a serif font.

The latter *may* end up something like this:

[image: Title font in Comic Sans]

But that *may* end up getting bunnies killed:

[image: Bunny-kills for using comic sans]

Bottom line: +1, good issue, but "no action required" IMO.

Comment: Woo QC ref woo! (You can vote for any reason or no reason at all, right? Yes? Good.)

Comment: Actually, I think Comic Sans is even worse: an isolated `l` could much easier be taken for an upper case `I` (if such `I` is not also used in the same title) than the current Trebuchet does.

Comment: It looks like what we *really* need is a variable-width programmer's font. Unfortunately, we also need to use a font that actually *exists*. (Anybody interested in creating one?)

Comment: @KeithThompson hehe good idea. We could just programmatically chop off all-but-one-pixel of whitespace on the sides of all Consolas glyphs, but then we'll all probably suffer [from this](http://xkcd.com/1015/).

Comment: @Jeroen: It's a bit scary that I knew what that link was before I opened it.