# Do we need less ambiguous question fonts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design, fonts

While reading through various questions, I noticed that while in code, tags (e.g., `iIl1`) are pretty easy to distinguish; in the standard font for questions, they are not (YMMV, but for all environments I have seen, they are not):

> iIl1

Of course not everyone has all fonts, but I was wondering if the CSS could be a better list, listing less ambiguous fonts earlier? Or maybe more fonts to increase the chances of people hitting a better, readable one? Currently the list is (at least displayed here):

```
Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif
```

It seems that this is done on math.se and electronics.se at least (Georgia,​ "Times New Roman", ​Times,​ serif), although I have no idea if that's for a reason, or some default setting that SO is deviating from. Or does SO maybe have a guideline somewhere behind the font decision that I overlooked?

The core of the question: do we need to "try harder" to get less ambiguous fonts (mostly for iIl1, but maybe for others too) used for normal question text (probably by choosing a serif font like math.se), or are there other, probably more important reasons to use/keep the current font?

Comment: If its a variable it should be inline code even within the text; so this this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @RichardTingle: I have been thinking about this numerous times and today stumbled over http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53341/ (not an SO question but I remember having similar issues on SO from time to time). In the mentioned answers, its not possible to distinguish them too (although in this specific case, I don't think its necessary). I just now noticed that the question title has a different font, but trying it out for questions/answers I personally find it rather ugly and hard to read, but it has a different l.

Comment: If you can provide links to a few existing questions where the ambiguity makes the title less useful, it would help to demonstrate the problem better.

Comment: @AdamDavis: Not the title, the question (and maybe the answer) body. I will try to dig some up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Title font makes I and l indistinct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142897/title-font-makes-i-and-l-indistinct)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Note how I am asking about the text of answers/questions, not the title (which now uses a different font solving that problem anyways). The question is less about the actual font, and more about if we actually care that such situations can arise. Also I find the answer there rather unsatisfying as it boils down to "The alternatives are not pretty, and we might end up with comic sans which sucks". I personally don't see a compelling reason why we don't use the same as math.se for SO.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. (BTW, the characters `I` and `l` still look very nearly identical in the title of that question, at least in my browser.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: ah, indeed, in see your comment about it there. It never occured to me that people just dont know how I looks like when they only see l. The whole issue seems to be quite different for new/inexperienced users.

Answer (score 6):

This is rendered unnecessary by inline codeblocks, denoted by backticks.

Any question which used iIl1 (or any other variable/function name) outside of a codeblock should have that wrapped in backticks to read `iIl1`.

Backticks are always going to be the better solution, especially considering that words themselves can also be ambiguous, and fonts can't help there:

> First I get the variable count then I decrement it

Which is the correct interpretation? Without backticks, it's pretty hard to tell:

- First I get the variable count then I decrement it?
- First I get the variable `count` then I decrement it
- First I get the variable count then I decrement `it`
- First I get the variable `count` then I decrement `it`?

Comment: This, exponentially. Don't forget you can edit posts.

Comment: Sure, and key combos even have these nice key like icons. But should we maybe think about if this is really necessary? It seems to me that a lot of questions that might have these problems (key combos as well as non-code text) are asked by rather inexperienced users, and then later edited by more experienced users. For one, during that time, the question is in a less-than-optimal state, and it is also using tiny amounts of resources that might be spent better elsewhere (review queue?).

Comment: I am not saying that either pov is the right one, I am just trying to view it from different points and collect -- more or less -- opinions and maybe some intresting statistics/studies? It might also turn out that this is just a similar case to http://xkcd.com/1015/ and most people don't care at all.

Comment: I would say that, unless we want to go with a monospace font specifically meant for viewing code, we're not going to solve this through font-selection alone. *Most* questions by new users are in a less-than-optimal state, ambiguous letters are a very, very small problem compared to things like large blocks of code lacking all formatting and indentation.

Comment: @meagar: I am not sure what point you are trying to make. The last part sounds like "we have other problems that should be solved first" but the "through font-selection alone" makes me think that it could be a part of it.

Comment: To clarify then: This is a solved problem, and I don't believe there is any value in reviewing our font selection.